# Subtracting values of a shared variable between two data frames with unequal size if their categorical variables are the same

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I wanted to compare the shared column, `value`, in two `dataframe` for year 2020 and 2019. The 2020 data has more rows since a new country has added to the table.
I wrote the below `function` but it didn’t produce any result. I would appreciate if anyone could help me on this.

```
dat2020 <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Gender, ~Indicator, ~value,  
  "Bangladesh", "Male", "A", 3.7,
  "Bangladesh", "Female", "A", 2.6,
  "Banggladesh", "Male", "B", 6.8,
  "Bangladesh", "Female", "B", 4.1,
  "China", "Male", "A", 7.6,
  "China", "Female", "A", 3.9,
  "China", "Male", "B", 1.5,
  "China", "Female", "B", 2.9,
  "Laos", "Male", "A", 7.6,
  "Laos", "Female", "A", 5.1,
  "Laos", "Male", "B", 3.8,
  "Laos", "Female", "B", 2.8,
)

dat2019 <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Gender, ~Indicator, ~value,  
  "Bangladesh", "Male", "A", 3.6,
  "Bangladesh", "Female", "A", 6.8,
  "Bangladesh", "Male", "B", 9.2,
  "Bangladesh", "Female", "B", 1.5,
  "China", "Male", "A", 8.5,
  "Chiina", "Female", "A", 3.9,
  "China", "Male", "B", 4.6,
  "China", "Female", "B", 5.3,
)

CheckList <- c()
checkValue <- function(data1, data2){
  if(data1$Country == data2$Country & data1$Gender == data2$Gender & data1$Indicator == data2$Indicator){
    CheckList$Diff = data1$value - data2$value
  }
  else{
    CheckList$Diff = NA
  }
}

checkValue(data1 = dat2019, data2 = dat2020)
```

My desired outcome: if a row in `dat2019` has exactly same categorical variables as in `dat2020`, return the difference between their `value` in 2020 and 2019.

Note there are intentional **typos** in dat2020 (Banggladesh) and dat2019 (Chiina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a join and subtract

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(dat2020, dat2019, by = names(dat2020)[1:3]) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = value.x - value.y, value = value.x, .keep = "unused")
```

Comment: Great. I like the way you use `suffixes` for non-key duplicate column `value` in `mutate`.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this via a `join` operation:

```
library(dplyr)

dat2019 %>% 
  dplyr::rename(value2019 = value) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(dplyr::rename(dat2020, value2020 = value)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(diff = value2020 - value2019)

#> Joining, by = c("Country", "Gender", "Indicator")
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#>   Country    Gender Indicator value2019 value2020  diff
#>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Bangladesh Male   A               3.6       3.7  0.1 
#> 2 Bangladesh Female A               6.8       2.6 -4.20
#> 3 Bangladesh Male   B               9.2      NA   NA   
#> 4 Bangladesh Female B               1.5       4.1  2.60
#> 5 China      Male   A               8.5       7.6 -0.9 
#> 6 Chiina     Female A               3.9      NA   NA   
#> 7 China      Male   B               4.6       1.5 -3.10
#> 8 China      Female B               5.3       2.9 -2.4
```